# How to make a jQuery plugin function callable for stand-alone use, that does not operate on a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I read the [jquery documentation of plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and am familiar with that. However, the examples given always operate on a set of previously matched elements. I want to create a function that can do both:

```
// example usage of my to-be-created plugin function

// this is the way described in the docs, and I know how to do that
$("a").myFunction ()

// but I also want to be able to call the function without a collection:
$.myFunction ();
```

If `$.myFunction ()`is called without a collection to operate on, it would create it's own collection of what elements to match - kind of an initialization process (but not necessarily run only once). Also, `$.myFunction ()`should maintain chainability.

The pseudocode of what I want to achieve:

```
// [...]
function myFunction (): {
    if (notCalledOnACollection) {
        // this should run when called via $.myFunction ()
        $elements = $("a.myClass");
    }
    else {
        $elements = $(this);
    }
    return $elements.each (function () {
        // do sth. here 
    });
}
```

I would really like to keep all of the functions implementation/functionality within a single function definition, and not have two separately named functions or two equally named functions in two separately places within the jQuery object.

And of course I could add a parameter `myFunction (do_init)` that indicates what branch of the `if` statement to execute, but that would clutter my argument list (I want to use that approach for multiple plugins, and there will be argumentes to `myFunction ()` that I just left out here for simplicity).

Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By simply adding another reference in the plugin definiton, you can easily use the standard plugin code:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.myPlugin = $.fn.myPlugin = function(myPluginArguments) {
        if(this.jquery)
            //"this" is a jquery collection, do jquery stuff with it
        } else {
            //"this" is not a jquery collection
        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin.otherFunc = function() {
    };
})( jQuery );
```

The only difference here is the `$.myPlugin =` part which allows you to directly call your plugin without running jquery's selector function.  Should you decide you need other functions or properties, you can create them as properties of your plugin.

Usage:

```
//using a selector (arguments optional)
$(".someClass").myPlugin();

//using the options variable - or whatever your arguments are
$.myPlugin({id: "someId"});

//accessing your other functions/properties
$.myPlugin.otherFunc();
```

Comment: I have serious issues with your solution. I've replicated your approach on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pnpbU/
But once I run `$.myPlugin ()`, all tested browser consume 100% CPU and get stuck (tested with FF on Linux & Windows, Safari on Mac).

Comment: I'm not seeing that issue on my machine.  And I'm on a dinosaur at the moment.  And besides, jsfiddle shouldn't be used for performance testing, they've got a bunch of extras loaded.  I also tested locally and didn't see the issue there, either.  I really doubt what your seeing has anything to do with this code.

Comment: Did you uncomment the line in the js part of jsfiddle? Else it would not run! I am at university right now and have access to a bunch of computers and I can reproduce the 100% cpu consume on 3 physically different machines. Using http://jsfiddle.net/pnpbU (with uncommenting the last line) and hitting run will block/end the script on Fedora 17: Firefox 14.0.1, Chrome 22; Windows 7: Firefox 14, IE9; OS X Lion: Safari 5, Firefox 14. So it is *definetely* reproducible. This has nothing to do with jsfiddle, copying that script together with jQuery 1.8.0 and run shows the same effect.

Comment: Ah, now I see where you are going wrong.. the issue is not with the code I have above, but rather the `$(this).each` you added to it.  When you don't send a selector, you can't use `this` in the same way (without a selector, no collection, hence no collection object).  I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DonamiteIsTNT/pnpbU/2/) to demonstrate the difference of the `this` object with and without a selector.

Comment: Ah you were right, I mixed up the if/else branch. I now do `if (this.jQuery === undefined) { // build the collection } /* do sth. with the collection */`

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense.  I'll update this answer, too, for anyone else's benefit.