# How to create a custom jquery function with brackets and parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, extend

I know that my question needs a little more clarification, so let me explain:

When I visited the jquery api documentation for $.fn.extend, I was personally blown away by how easy it was to create a custom jquery function like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').check();
```

Link here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

But if you wanted to add functionality to the function like this (pun intended):

```
check({ timer: 1000, redo: 4000, displayAt: 'someID' });

// filler parameters
```

How would you do that, exactly?

Also, how would you create a function like `check({ ... });` that does not rely on any specific jquery selectors, but instead could just be called like a regular function like this:

```
displayRandomNumber({ min: 0, max: 100, displayAt: 'someID'}); 

// so no jquery selector in front.
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a jQuery plugin function callable for stand-alone use, that does not operate on a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419658/how-to-make-a-jquery-plugin-function-callable-for-stand-alone-use-that-does-not)

Comment: Just create a regular function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use:

```
check({ timer: 1000, redo: 4000, displayAt: 'someID' });
```

with jquery.fn.extend your function would be declared like so:

```
check: function(options) {
    // Get the timer value
    var timerValue = options.timer;
    // Get the redo value
    var redoValue = options.redo;
    ...
}
```

Standalone, it would look like this:

```
function check(options) {
    // Get the timer value
    var timerValue = options.timer;
    // Get the redo value
    var redoValue = options.redo;
    ...
}
```